# opencv_createsamples: command not found

Tags: python, linux, opencv, computer-vision, opencv3.0

Everytime I run the command `opencv_createsamples`, I am hit with this error. I know that I need to run `opencv` from the src but I am not sure how to fully do so. Can somebody give me a detailed and simplified explanation of how I would go about this?

Comment: Yes, you are right. This problem also mentioned [here](https://answers.opencv.org/question/194966/opencv_createsamples-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/). You can follow [this tutorial series](https://pythonprogramming.net/haar-cascade-object-detection-python-opencv-tutorial/). I think the solution to your problem is inside those tutorials.

Comment: Nope it does not work, there is noting there

Comment: Which python version are you using?