# opencv_createsamples: command not found ubuntu

Tags: opencv, haar-classifier, ubuntu-20.04, createsamples

I am following [Creating your own Haar Cascade OpenCV Python Tutorial](https://pythonprogramming.net/haar-cascade-object-detection-python-opencv-tutorial/) But when I get to making the samples I get `opencv_createsamples: command not found`

I am using this to create the samples `opencv_createsample -img img.jpg -bg bg.txt -info info/info.lst -pngoutput info -maxxangle 0.5 -maxyangle 0.5 -maxzangle 0.5 -num 573`

but I know the command exists because when I do `man opencv_createsamples` it pulls up the man page.
I am using ubuntu 20.04.1

Comment: What is opencv version

Comment: Latest opencv version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have also met this same problem while trying to get **Haar Cascade**. Similar problem also mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61977772/opencv-createsamples-command-not-found).

According to @Alekhin saying [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/14322):

> To be able to use `opencv_createsamples` command, you should use
> opencv version 3.x or lower.

This step(creating samples) is only necessary to get our samples. So my suggestions:

1. Installing supported opencv version in a docker and getting samples
2. Installing supported opencv in another machine and getting samples

**Note:** I don't suggest you to install opencv while other one already exist in your machine.

Same problems also mentioned [here](https://github.com/mrnugget/opencv-haar-classifier-training/issues/4) and [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/13231).

[For opencv installation on a docker.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36862589/install-opencv-in-a-docker-container)

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ubuntu 20.04, and I had the same problem.

I recommend using the Conda environment with the following Python version:

```
conda create -n NAME python=3.6.13
```

Also, install `OpenCv version 3.4.0` and it will be solved.