# How to train cascade using opencv

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, createsamples

I want to train my own cascade.
At tutorial they say to use `opencv_createsamples` and

`opencv_traincascade` command.

However I cant use that commands.

[image]

My opencv folder:

```
opencv>> apps >> annotation      
         build   createsamples            
         cmake   traincascade  
           .     visualisation
           .     CMakeLists.txt  
           .     interactive-calibration  
                 version
```

My opencv version is 4.1.1

How can I do this?

Comment: What version of OpenCV are you using?

Comment: I'm using 4.1.1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [opencv\_createsamples: command not found ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63305283/opencv-createsamples-command-not-found-ubuntu)

Comment: did you try createsamples instead of opencv_createsamples, as your ls command shows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With newer versions of OpenCV they do not include the cascade training binaries anymore (because opencv tries to get rid of the old C code). You will have to use an older version if you want it to work. Cascade classifiers trained with older opencv version binaries should still be usable with the latest opencv lib for object detection.

[Read this link](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/13231)